# Rails application stores incorrect time in datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I create a model, the two datetime fields are created (created_at and updated_at).  Whenever I create a new instance of the object the times for those two fields are 5 hours ahead of my current time.  I set config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)' inside config/locales/application.rb but that doesn't help.

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 2):

By design, active record always stores UTC dates in the database. These are converted into the timezone specified by `Time.zone` (which defaults to `config.time_zone`) when displayed to the user. Similarly if you had a date/time select in one of your forms then that time would be converted from `Time.zone` to UTC before storage in the database.

Assuming that DST is in effect where you're based then 5 hours ahead of your local time is UTC.